# How to simplify setTimeout in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, jsx, react-component

There was a typewriting animation in pure javaScript which has been converted to ReactJS. The `setTimeout` functions do not look clean and do not adhere to best practices according to ReactJS standard.

For example `animationManager()`

```
animationManager = () => {
  this.rafRef = requestAnimationFrame(time => {
    const typingData = this.props.data;
    this.typeEffect(time, typingData[this.index], () => {
      this.timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => {
        this.rafRef = requestAnimationFrame(time => {
          this.deleteEffect(time, () => {
            this.timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => {
              this.index =
                this.index === typingData.length - 1 ? 0 : this.index + 1;
              this.animationManager();
            }, this.props.pauseBeforeRestarting);
          });
        });
      }, this.props.pauseBeforeDeleting);
    });
  });
};
```

Is it possible to make it more clean with all these `setTimout` ?

Complete code  https://codesandbox.io/s/qk4591q1kw

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is working  as is. The question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a lot less to do with setTimeout than simply refactoring, I would wrap each callback into a promise and call them via await

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I am sorry to see your close vote. Unfortunately there no even views in codereview page https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/reactjs-typewriting-animation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can actually create functions that acts like a timer: it returns a promise that is resolved when the time runs out, something like this:

```js
timer = (duration) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}
```

Similarly, you can do the same for `requestAnimationFrame`. The trick is to use ES6 spread operator so that you can pass arbitrary number of arguments into the callback to be invoked:

```js
animationFrame = (callback, ...args) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(time => {
      callback(time, ...args);
    });
  })
}
```

Since you are using ES6, you can then use `async` functions to wait for the timer to complete, before moving on to execute the next line of code. If we break down your `animationManager()` code, it can be seen as following:

1. You want to start with `typingEffect`
2. Once `typingEffect` is completed, you want to trigger `deleteEffect`

In this case, we can refactor your code as such:

```js
animationManager = () => {
  const deleteFunc = (time, typingData) => {
    this.deleteEffect(time, async () => {
      await this.timer(this.props.pauseBeforeRestarting);
      this.index = this.index === typingData.length - 1 ? 0 : this.index + 1;
      this.animationManager();
    });
  };

  const typeFunc = (time) => {
    const typingData = this.props.data;
    this.typeEffect(time, typingData[this.index], async () => {
      await this.timer(this.props.pauseBeforeDeleting);
      await this.animationFrame(deleteFunc, typingData);
    })
  };

  this.animationFrame(typeFunc);
};
```

I have forked your example to provide a proof-of-concept of the slightly refactored code: https://codesandbox.io/s/308kxjzwrq

Comment: Thank you very much for your help buddy. FYI https://codesandbox.io/s/308kxjzwrq still same as the original code

Comment: @Mo. My bad, looks like I forgot to hit save :) fixed now!

Comment: got it, looks awesome 

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) for that. You can create helper Promise which will use requestAnimationFrame, and make your flow flat and "thenable", by adding success callbacks onResolve.